# Annoying list of error messages pointing to missing Myriad Pro font

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, moderncv

I'm getting an awfully annoying list of error messages pointing to Myriad Pro font missing when I use moderncv and xelatex or lulatex:

```
\setmainfont{Myriad Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
```

the whole error messages as follows:

```
line 90: fontspec error: "font-not-found"! The font "Myriad Pro" cannot be found. ^^I\setmainfont{Myriad Pro}
line 90: fontspec error: "font-not-found"! The font "Myriad Pro" cannot be found. ^^I\setmainfont{Myriad Pro}
line 90: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/10.95="Myriad Pro:" at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ^^I\setmainfont{Myriad Pro}
line 91: fontspec error: "font-not-found"! The font "Myriad Pro" cannot be found. ^^I\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
line 94: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/10="Myriad Pro:" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ^^I\vspace
line 94: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/34="Myriad Pro:" at 34.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ^^I\vspace
line 94: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/17.28="Myriad Pro:" at 17.28pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ^^I\vspace
line 96: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/14.4="Myriad Pro:" at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ^^I\section{Objetivo}
line 119: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/bx/n/10.95="Myriad Pro:" at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ^^I^^I\end{itemize}}
line 131: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/7="Myriad Pro:" at 7.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ^^I^^I\end{itemize}}
line 136: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/it/10="Myriad Pro:" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ...in, central Peruvian convergent margin"}}
line 136: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/it/10.95="Myriad Pro:" at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ...in, central Peruvian convergent margin"}}
line 155: Font EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/8="Myriad Pro:" at 8.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ...#}, SQL, \LaTeX, JavaScript, PHP, Python}
: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
: You have requested package `moderncvstylefork', but the package provides `moderncvstyleclassic'.
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/10.95' does not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,(microtype) protrusion will not work with this font.
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/10' does not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,(microtype) protrusion will not work with this font.
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/34' does not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,(microtype) protrusion will not work with this font.
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/17.28' does not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,(microtype) protrusion will not work with this font.
line 94: Overfull \vbox (117.07455pt too high) detected
line 94: Font shape `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/sl' undefined(Font) using `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n' instead
line 94: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 96: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/14.4' does not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,(microtype) protrusion will not work with this font.
line 99: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
line 102: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
line 111: Font shape `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/bx/n' undefined(Font) using `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n' instead
line 111: Font shape `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/it' undefined(Font) using `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n' instead
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/bx/n/10.95' does not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,(microtype) protrusion will not work with this font.
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/7' does not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,(microtype) protrusion will not work with this font.
line 133: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/it/10' does not specify its
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/it/10.95' does not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,(microtype) protrusion will not work with this font.
line 149: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
line 154: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
: Font `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n/8' does not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,(microtype) protrusion will not work with this font.
line 160: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
line 164: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
line 167: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
line 170: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\BooleanFalse'
: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

I reinstalled MikTek 2.9 in Windows as well as TexStudio 2.8.8. This error appeared once with TexStudio 2.8.6 and never appeared with 2.8.4. What is wrong here? I understand that Myriad Pro comes with MikTek, this is because I have only upgraded TexStudio over the last year or so.

I'd appreciate your support on this, thanks in advance,

EDIT:

Installing adobe reader and rebooting did the trick, this because paths need to be updated according to:

```
--- /cygdrive/c/Users/Gery/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fontconfig/config/localfonts.conf 2015-01-09 12:54:02.749021900 -0500
+++ /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/fontconfig/config/localfonts.conf        2015-01-09 11:42:05.469025600 -0500
@@ -8,9 +8,6 @@
 <fontconfig>
 <include>localfonts2.conf</include>
 <dir>C:\Windows\Fonts</dir>
-<dir>C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Resource\Font</dir>
-<dir>C:\Users\Gery\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\type1</dir>
-<dir>C:\Users\Gery\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\truetype</dir>
 <dir>C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\type1</dir>
 <dir>C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\opentype</dir>
 </fontconfig>
```

Comment: Myriad Pro does not come with miktex, but with the adobe reader. miktex only adds the path to fonts (if it can find it) to localfonts.conf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for that, I didn't have adobe reader, now it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by comment.